# How to mock mongodb manager in typescript using jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

How can I return a mongodb.connection.db() type value and mock its collection?
I create a mongoClient type connection and use its db() function. If all works work correctly, I enter the collection information of this but i couldn't write test of it because i can't mock it.

`dbManager.ts`

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

class DBManager {
  private connection?: MongoClient;
  private mongoUrl = null;

  constructor(url: string) {
    this.mongoUrl = url;
  }

  get db() {
    return this.connection!.db();
  }

  async start() {
    if (!this.connection) {
      this.connection = await MongoClient.connect(this.mongoUrl);
    }
  }
}

export default DBManager;
```

`index.ts`

```
 const dbManager = new DBManager(url);
  await dbManager.start();
  const db = dbManager.db;

  if (db) {
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
  }
```

`index.spec.ts`

```
  const dbManager = new DBManager( 'mongoUrl');
      jest.spyOn(dbManager, 'start').mockResolvedValue();
      jest.spyOn(dbManager, 'db', 'get').mockImplementation();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the mock is not successful is that you created a new `DBManager` instance in the test case, and `jest.spyOn()` only adds spy to the method of this instance. In the tested code is another instance of `DBManager`, still calling its original, unspy method.

You can add spy to `DBManager.prototype.start()` and `DBManager.prototype.get()` methods.

Besides, don't forget to restore mocks back to their original value in `afterEach` hook. To ensure that the mock object of the test case will not affect other test cases.

E.g.

`DBManager.ts`:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

class DBManager {
  private connection?: MongoClient;
  private mongoUrl: string = '';

  constructor(url: string) {
    this.mongoUrl = url;
  }

  get db() {
    return this.connection!.db();
  }

  async start() {
    if (!this.connection) {
      this.connection = await MongoClient.connect(this.mongoUrl);
    }
  }
}

export default DBManager;
```

`index.ts`:

```
import DBManager from './dbManager';

export async function main() {
  const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
  const collectionName = 'user';
  const dbManager = new DBManager(url);
  await dbManager.start();
  const db = dbManager.db;

  if (db) {
    const collection = db.collection(collectionName);
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```
import { main } from './';
import DBManager from './dbManager';
import { Db } from 'mongodb';

describe('69011729', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const mDB = ({
      collection: jest.fn(),
    } as unknown) as Db;
    jest.spyOn(DBManager.prototype, 'start').mockResolvedValue();
    jest.spyOn(DBManager.prototype, 'db', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(mDB);
    await main();
    expect(DBManager.prototype.start).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mDB.collection).toBeCalledWith('user');
  });

  test('should restore original methods', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(DBManager.prototype.start)).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/69011729/index.test.ts (10.734 s)
  69011729
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)
    ✓ should restore original methods

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.516 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```